Can you define $\exp(x)$, $\sin(x)$ or other functions through their Taylor series?
Isn't it circular reasoning? I've read it on a calculus book, but it's something I've heard pretty often. To me, that's wrong, since then you would use the Taylor series to get the derivative of $\exp x$, but that's something you need to get to the series in the first place.

Taylor series can be proven by repeated differentiation. Once it is proven, you can use one to find the other. Right?

If you define $\exp(x) \equiv \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n/n!$, then you don't need anything to get the series. It's just given. You would however need to prove that the series satisfies other notable properties of $\exp$.

It is perfectly fine to define the exponential and trigonometric series by their MacLaurin series. Then you need to prove the interesting properties of these functions using the series definitions. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744427/show-by-series-definition-of-exponential-function-that-exp-x-rightarrow-0 for an example.

In Walter Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, the first chapter starts with the series definition of $\exp(x)$ and derives all of the relevant properties of the exponential, sine, and cosine just from that.

I can define SQUARE as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (2n-1)$ and declare then notation as $n^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (2n-1)$ and then later I can prove that $n^2 = n\times n$.  There's nothing circular about that. Even though my "circular" definition was derived from the "real" definition, I never used the "real" definition and my derived definition was self-contained.

@fleablood This is genius! Made my day.

There's usually more than one way to define a function. For example, $e^x=\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x/n)^n$. From any  given definition, you can often use it to derive the associated Taylor Series. For many equations, say $dy/dx=y$, you can start off assuming the function can be expressed as some power series, then figure out what the coefficients have to be to satisfy the equation. The result is the taylor series.

It is not a circular definition. I think what is throwing you off is the term Taylor series which for you seems to mean that you need to have a function $f$ to begin with and then
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!} (x-a)^n $$
would be the corresponding Taylor series.
Consider the following slightly different point of view. Pick a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the series (more precisely, a power series)
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $$
converges. That means for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ this series spits out a number, which is exactly what a function does! So we can define a function $f(x)$ to be given by
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n. $$
In fact there is a whole zoo of such functions (they are called real-analytic functions). For these functions, one prove that they are actually infinitely often differentiable and that
$$ f^{(n)}(0) = n! a_n, $$
respectively, that their MacLaurin series is given by
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n. $$
It is perfectly fine to take a power series and turn it into a function, once we have shown that is converges (and this is always the tough part).
